# Lemma, Grundform-Lexikon deutscher Sprache

Tags: online-resource

Gibt es irgendwo eine Quelle, die mir ein Lexikon aller deutschen Lemmata (Grundformen) - am besten frei - zur Verfügung stellt? Und am besten auch, ohne vorher eine Lizenz einzureichen wie bspw. bei *Germanet* und Konsorten?

Ich benötige ein Lexikon dieser Art, um es anschließend in alle Morpheme und Allomorphe aufzuteilen.
Oder gibt es schon ein fertiges semantisches Netz, mit dem man arbeiten kann?

Answer (score 4):

#### [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/)

Canoo bietet zu jedem Wort in ihrer recht umfassenden Datenbank auch eine Funktion die Wörter nach ihrem Stamm zu zerlegen, und listet auch alle Ableitungen aus diesem Stamm auf (Link zu "Wortbildung" für jedes eingegebene Wort).

Sollte ein Wort nicht archiviert sein, bietet Canoo auch einen "[Unknown Word Analyzer](http://www.canoo.net/languageexperts/products/toolkit/?l=de#unknown)":

> Der Unknown Word Analyzer liefert morphosyntaktische Information für ein bekanntes Wort oder ein unbekanntes Wort (d.h. für ein Wort ausserhalb des Lexikons): z.B. Grundform, Wortkategorie, Geschlecht, Tempus, Hilfsverben zusammen mit allen möglichen Zerlegungen und Ableitungen sowie den Wortkategorien der jeweiligen Elemente.<sup>[Canoo](http://www.canoo.net/languageexperts/products/toolkit/?l=de#unknown)</sup>

#### Beispiele

Man erhälttn für das Beispiel "[Erlebnispark](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=Erlebnispark&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=de)" folgendes Ergebnis nach Auswahl "Wortbildung":

```
Erlebnis ->  
                    Erlebnispark, Nomen  
Park ->
```

Erlebnis ist zum Wörtebucheintrag verlinkt. Dort wird die [Wortbildung](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/erlebnis:N:N) weiter aufgeschlüsselt in:

[image]

Dort sind erneut die Wortstämme zum Wörterbucheintrag verlinkt, so dass man alle Ableitungen des Verbs "[leben](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/leben:V:haben)" auflisten kann.

Manchmal muss man sich etwas durch die verlinkten Einträge hangeln, aber man erhält in der Regel sehr brauchbare Ergebnisse.

Hier ein weiteres Beispiel für das Verb "[lieben](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=lieben&features=(Cat%20V)(Aux%20haben)&dispatch=wordformation&lang=de)":

[image]

Jeder Eintrag in diesem Suchergebnis ist weiter verlinkt. So erhält man mit Klick auf "[Liebe](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/liebe:N:F)" alle weiteren Ableitungen aus dem Nomen und unter "[lieb](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/lieb:A)" die Ableitungen vom Adjektiv.

Comment: Das sieht schon mal ganz nett aus. Danke dafür.

Comment: This is amazing O.o

Answer (score 2):

Eine Menge mit allen Begriffen einer Sprache existiert nicht. Maximal kann man mit einer grammatischen Theorie alle Instanzen von Worttypen in einem Corpus sammeln und mit einer lexikalischen Theorie Worttypen wie Formen von Begriffen betrachten. So kann man auftretende Begriffe sammeln und ihre Grundformen konstruieren. Es gibt deswegen größere und kleinere Sammlungen von Begriffen, die mit Hilfe unterschiedlicher Theorien geschaffen wurden.

Wofür brauchst Du eine Sammlung von Begriffen und Grundformen?