# Is there a type of German dictionary where words with the same “root” are listed together?

Tags: resource, dictionary

Is there a German dictionary that lists words with the same root together, e.g., where *abstimmen*, *mitbestimmen*, *zustimmen* etc. are listed under *stimmen*?

Comment: Not that I would know of. Your example is a good one insofar as it shows the questionable use of such a list - the composed verbs use the common root "Stimme" == *vote*, while "stimmen" (which you assume to be a 'final' root) goes back to another root meaning *tune* (both roots have another common one == *voice*). I am not sure what you would want to achieve which such lists.

Comment: Would wildcards in an electronic dictionary help? E.g. `*stimmen` in [Canoo](http://canoo.net/services/Controller?input=*stimmen) or [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=*stimmen).

Comment: @Crissov Right, thanks. "Dictionary" normally makes my brain switch to "paper mode"

Comment: Many thanks, tofro and @Crissov, for your answers. I hadn't tried wildcards, but have just tried them in Leo and got what I was looking for. Perfect.

Comment: @tofro - Your comment is absolutely right, and that's one thing I've been trying to get a hold of. I wanted to visualise the different (but related) meanings of **stimmen** (and the nouns, adjectives etc. related to them). I'm at the stage of hoovering up vocabulary and trying to make sense of it... :-)

Comment: @Crissov I have just checked, the wildcard `*stimmen` also works with the CD-ROM versions of the Duden dictionaries.

Comment: @Loong … but not on the website as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**Canoonet**](http://canoonet.eu/index_en.html) offers quite a nice clickable word formation tree for many word stems including *[stimmen](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=stimmen&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=en)*.

A click on *[Wordformation](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=stimmen&features=(Cat%20V)(Aux%20haben)&dispatch=wordformation&lang=en)* will lead to the following tree (only shown in part):

[image]

One level above would be for the stem *[Stimme](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/stimme:N:F)* with even more derivations.

Also see this related question (in German):

- [Lemma, Grundform-Lexikon deutscher Sprache](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15838/lemma-grundform-lexikon-deutscher-sprache)

Comment: A really nice one I didn't know! +1 for the enlightenment!

Comment: As of 2023 this website is defunct and the shown functionality not available publicly anymore by their successors: "Die Technologie, die für die Wortbildung verwendet wurde, verblieb bei der IMTF. Diese Informationen sind daher bei LEO leider nicht in gleichem Umfang verfügbar. Sie können eine Wörterbuchsuche mit * (z.B. \*terrasse\*) verwenden, um zusammengesetzte Begriffe zu finden. Die weitergehenden Informationen können wir aber leider nicht bieten" from https://dict.leo.org/pages/about/ende/canoonet_de.html

Answer (score 2):

Howard Kellerʹs 1978 "A German Word Family Dictionary" is pretty useful.

Answer (score 2):

The Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache offers the word list you are looking for.

E.g.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/stimmen

Scroll down the screen till "Etymologie", and click on the blue "Mehr"

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.verbformen.com/ and scroll down to the right to "Derivatives." (Not all verbs are provided with a list.)For example, for können:

≡ abkönnen
≡ ankönnen
≡ dafürkönnen
≡ dazukönnen
≡ durchkönnen
≡ fortkönnen
≡ heimkönnen
≡ herankönnen
≡ herkönnen
≡ hinkönnen
≡ hochkönnen
≡ loskönnen
≡ mitkönnen
≡ nachkönnen
≡ rankönnen
≡ rauskönnen
≡ reinkönnen
≡ umhinkönnen
≡ wegkönnen
Also check Reverso Conjugation at https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-rules-model-german.html. Under "Models" you will find lists of verbs which conjugate the same. Most have the same stems.
Then go to In general, the prefix be- makes the verb transitive, intensifies the meaning and shifts focus to the direct object. Often the verb with be- can acquire a completely new meaning over time.
If you can face the discouragement, go to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Pr%C3%A4fixe#Pr%C3%A4fixe_mit_Verben. But be prepared to cry.

Answer (score 0):

My Wortbildungswoerterbuch is unfortunately only available in a few English university libraries, but I started with the compact but reliable Sprach-Brockhaus which is still available if you are prepared to pay rather inflated second-hand prices.